# Add social media icons (shortcode) to navigation bar

Tags: html, css, wordpress, shortcode

Hey I'm trying to add icons to my top navigation bar.

I have a plugin for social media icons, so I am trying to add the plugin shortcode to the nav menu.  I downloaded a plugin to allow me to add shortcode to a menu.

Here is the shortcode I want to add: `[feather_follow show="twitter, google_plus, facebook" hide="reddit, pinterest, linkedin, tumblr, mail"]`

I tried adding `size="16"` to make the images smaller but it made them disappear completely. Please visit my site to see the results I am getting. Containers and sizing are all screwed up, I have no idea how to begin fixing this.

Can anyone take a quick look and suggest anything? I would REALLY appreciate it.  I have already wasted hours and hours on this simple problem.  My site is [greenenvysupply.com](http://www.greenenvysupply.com)

Comment: Could you tell us what plugin you are using, that will most likely provide the best clues to your issue. My guess is that the shortcode does not accept a `size attribute`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this

```
[feather_follow size="64" show="twitter, google_plus, facebook" hide="reddit, pinterest, linkedin, tumblr, mail"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use percentages for making your icons smaller without losing the ratio of the icons. So you can write something like this in your main CSS:

```
.top-bar ul>li a {
    width: auto!important;
    height: auto!important;
}

.top-bar ul>li a img {
    position: relative;
    width: 30%!important;
    height: 50%!important;
}
```

Comment: thank you! the first part of the code solved the width issue.  I am now having a problem with a style of "margin-bottom:10px".  I need to remove it using custom CSS and I have tried everything with no avail.  Could you take a quick look? <a class="synved-social-button synved-social-button-follow synved-social-size-18 synved-social-resolution-single synved-social-provider-facebook nolightbox"</a>

Comment: This should work for you: .top-bar ul>li a {margin-bottom: 0px!important;}